# Page fadeOut when links are clicked, except mailto: links

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

in the below code, I am fading out any page, and then fading in the new page, when any  tag is clicked. However, there are certain instances where we don't want to fade the page out on click, for example, when an  tag is set to open externally via `target="_blank"`. The code below reflects this and is working successfully.

However, one thing I'm not sure how to achieve, is to prevent the fade out when a link contains a mailto: reference, as obviously this is designed to open a mailing client window. Therefore I don't want the page to fade out?

Thank you.

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});

(function($) {
    if (window.history) {
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            $("body").show();
        });
    }

    // When links are clicked
    $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var $link   = $(this);
    var $href   = $link.attr("href");
    var $target = $link.attr("target");

        // If link exists
        if ($href) {
            // Fade out all links unless set to open in external window target="_blank"
            if ($target !== "_blank") {
                $("body").fadeOut(250, function() {
                    history.pushState($href, null, null);
                    window.location.href = $href;
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    // On page load, fade in
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").fadeTo(250, 1);
    });
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: If there are not a lot of links, i'd be tempted to recommend instead, put a class of 'external' on the links that you don't want to fade out.  Then your delegate matcher would just change to `.on('click', 'a:not(.external)', ...)`

Comment: HI @Taplar - there are many links on the site so looking for something more universal, rather than just a class name. thanks.

Comment: Jameson's solution below effectively does my suggestion without the need for an extra class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a very elegant way to do this is to use the awesome power of the css attribute selector and pass the validation so you only need this:

```
$(document).on('click','a[href]:not([href^=mailto],[target="_blank"])',function(){
     $("body").fadeOut(250, function() {
         history.pushState(this.href, null, null);
         window.location.href = this.href;
     });
     return false;
})
```

this is where the "magic" happens: `a[href]:not([href^=mailto],[target="_blank"])` (UPDATED to include the "has `href`" clause

I only select links that the href does not start with `mailto` and do not have `target="_blank"`

more on attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: You should include his first check. If `a` has an `href`

Comment: Hi many thanks for the answer. Looks great, how is support for this?

Comment: support will surprise you, as stated in the link to mozilla - it works in IE7 and up, more so if you use jQuery (and you do)

Answer (score 2):

Simply check the link url:

```
if($href.indexOf('mailto:') === 0){
  //the url starts with mailto:
  //it is an email link
}
```

More specific to your usecase, extend the if statement where you check for `_blank`:

```
if ($target !== "_blank" && $href.indexOf('mailto:') !== 0) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zammy. Lots of good answers here but have marked this as correct for addressing my particular use case. Works a treat.

Comment: Thanks, I have to give credit to @Jameson the dog tho. I'd recommend using his answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For a link that contains a `mailto:` reference just change this part in your code

```
if ($href) {
```

with this

```
if ($href && $href.indexOf('mailto:')!==-1) {
```

Alternatively check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g9dryzt/1) demonstrating the usage of `:not`. In your case don't forget to use `event.preventDefault()` for the mailto links from opening mail client window.